# Stable eigenspace of $x'=Ax$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Given the system $\bf{x'}=Ax$, where $\bf{A}$$=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 &0  &0 \\ 
 2& 1 & 0\\ 
0 &0  &1 
\end{bmatrix}$, the solution is $x(t) = \begin{bmatrix}
e^{-2t} & 0 &0 \\ 
\frac{-2}{3} e^{-2t}+\frac{2}{3} e^t & e^t &0 \\ 
 0& 0 &e^t 
\end{bmatrix}$. Now, the stable eigenspace $E^s=span\begin{Bmatrix}
{\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\2 
\\ 0
\end{bmatrix}}
\end{Bmatrix}$. To find the set of vectors $S:=x\in\mathbb{R}^3:\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} e^{At}x=0$, in my understanding, we need to consider:

$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}x(t)=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}e^{At}x = \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\begin{bmatrix}
e^{-2t}x_1\\(-\frac{2}{3}e^{-2t}+\frac{2}{3}e^t)x_1+e^tx_2) 
\\ e^tx_3
\end{bmatrix}=\vec{0}$. But the only vector satisfying this condition is the vector where $x_1=x_2=x_3= 0$, that is, the zero vector! But how is this possible? If the stable eigenspace $E^s$ has a basis, the set $S$ must contain some vectors besides the zero vector. What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second component you have the term $(\frac23x_1+x_2)e^t$, and so you can take $x_2=-\frac23 x_1$ (the numbers $x_2$ and $x_3$ need not be zero). The third line gives $x_3=0$. So, you get all scalar multiples of the basis for the stable space (as it should).